# How Do I Add Event Handlers to .NET Buttons Programmatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, event-handling

I'm trying to employ the strongest OOP I can muster in developing a web application, but I'm having issues adding event handlers to my objects as I create them using code.  I'm sure it's a fairly simple solution that I just keep passing up, but I'm at a loss as to what to try next.  Below is some test code I've been playing with, just trying to get a button press to go do something.

(Imagine there's a break point on the line "int i;")

```
    Button b = new Button();
    b.Text = "Do Something";
    b.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
    b.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "click");
    form1.Controls.Add(b);

    private void click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i;
    }
```

Since this is a new button created by my Page_Load, I can't just hardcode the XHTML.  Debugging never hits my breakpoint.  I haven't had any more success with CheckBoxes either.

Comment: Usually you use delegate functions in C#. What framework specifically are you targeting?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to subscribe to the `Click` event:

```
Button b = new Button();
b.Text = "Do Something";
b.Click += click;
form1.Controls.Add(b);

private void click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i;
}
```

By adding the `onclick` Attribute to the Button's `Attributes` collection, it will be rendered as an attribute on the HTML input tag. In that case you could use it to execute some javascript code on the client side.

```
b.Attributes.Add("onclick", "alert('Hey')");

//Will render the button as
<input type="submit" name="x" value="Do Something" onclick="alert('Hey')">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
Button b = new Button();
b.Text = "Do Something";
b.Click += new EventHandler((s, ev) =>
                        {
                            int i;
                        });
form1.Controls.Add(b);
```